# Can I Protect My Origin IP using urlrewrite and Cloudflare?

Tags: security, iis, url-rewriting, ip, cloudflare

Will my urlrewrite rule (IIS) adequately protect my Origin IP?

I'm trying  to disallow connections using either:

1. an IP address directly; or
2. another Cloudflare website domain name that may be pointed to my IP address.

My proposed urlrewrite rule (Allow connection only for myname.com):

```
<rule name="Allow only myname.com"  stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myname\.com$" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" /></rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no need to use url rewrite to protect your IP address. IIS will check the host name by default, if you add the hostname in the binding.

For example,

If you add the hostname in the binding as below image shows.

[image]

If you access the application by using IP address, it will show 400 error as below:

[image]

If you used the different domain like localhost.

[image]